# Transform a switch case code into configuration file

Tags: c#, app-config

I have the following switch case code :

```
  public string Channel
    {
        get
        {
            switch (OriginCode)
            {
                case "EMAI":
                    return "Local Site";
                case "TEL":
                    return "Local Site";

                case "WBE":
                    {
                        if (CompanyName != null)
                        {
                            if (CompanyName.ToUpper().Contains("REMOTE SITE"))
                            {
                                return "REMOTE SITE";

                            }
                            else if (CompanyName.ToUpper().Contains("FOREIGN CHANNEL"))
                            {
                                return "FOREIGN CHANNEL";

                            }
                            else
                                return "OTHER";

                        }
                        else return "UNKN";
                    }
                default:
                    return "UNKN";

            }

        }
        set
        {
            Channel = value;
        }
    }
```

I would like to transform this using a configuration file with all mappings so that this can be easily maintainable in the future.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Do you have any code or examples of what you tried already?

Comment: Somewhere to start [MSDN - ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The original code is buggy, by the way. The option "REMOTE SITE 2" can never be hit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have modified the strings.